# Cronjob to exec into a pod and print output of a command

Tags: kubernetes, cron, exec, jobs

I am trying to put this command

```
kubectl exec -t pod/phase4c-helloworld-7b8bb54559-lsl4t -n phase4c -- /bin/bash -c "echo testing1
```

in a script and run as cronjob. This is a simple version of my script. I want to run commands in the container and get the output to a file.

But getting an error => Must be running in a tty to pass the '--tty flag'.

How can I get the output to a file like this :

```
00 05 * * sun /home/dcosadmin/scripts/imageCleanup.sh > /tmp/cleanup.out
```

Comment: you can also use `kubectl logs <podname>` command to see the stdout.

Comment: How would you run similar tasks without containers involved; how would you run a script inside another process?  Could you instead use a Kubernetes CronJob to launch a separate Pod on an interval?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-t` argument. It’s the TTY option.